# Groovy: Is there a better way of handling @Immutable objects than copyWith method

Tags: groovy, immutability

I am looking for a flexible way of "modifying" (copying with some values changed) immutable objects in groovy. There is a copyWith method but it allows you only to replace some properties of the object. It doesn't seem to be convenient enough.

Let's say we have a set of classes representing a domain design of some system:

```
@Immutable(copyWith = true)
class Delivery {
    String id
    Person recipient
    List<Item> items
}

@Immutable(copyWith = true)
class Person {
    String name
    Address address
}

@Immutable(copyWith = true)
class Address {
    String street
    String postalCode
}
```

Let's assume I need to change street of delivery recipient. In case of regular mutable object it is just fine to perform:

```
delivery.recipient.address.street = newStreet
```

or (perhaps useful in some cases):

```
delivery.with {recipient.address.street = newStreet}
```

When it comes to do the same with immutable objects the best way according to my knowledge would be:

```
def recipient = delivery.recipient
def address = recipient.address
delivery.copyWith(recipient:
                      recipient.copyWith(address:
                                             address.copyWith(street: newStreet)))
```

It is actually needed for Spock integration test code so readability and expressiveness matters. The version above cannot be used "on the fly" so in order to avoid creating tons of helper methods, I have implemented my own *copyOn* (since *copyWith* was taken) method for that which makes it possible to write:

**def deliveryWithNewStreet = delivery.copyOn { it.recipient.address.street = newStreet }**

I wonder however if there is an ultimate solution for that, present in groovy or provided by some external library. Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with your copyOn implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I provide my implementation of copyOn method. It goes as follows:

```
class CopyingDelegate {
    static <T> T copyOn(T source, Closure closure) {
        def copyingProxy = new CopyingProxy(source)
        closure.call(copyingProxy)
        return (T) copyingProxy.result
    }
}

class CopyingProxy {
    private Object nextToCopy
    private Object result
    private Closure copyingClosure

    private final Closure simplyCopy = { instance, property, value -> instance.copyWith(createMap(property, value)) }
    private final def createMap = { property, value -> def map = [:]; map.put(property, value); map }

    CopyingProxy(Object nextToCopy) {
        this.nextToCopy = nextToCopy
        copyingClosure = simplyCopy
    }

    def propertyMissing(String propertyName) {
        def partialCopy = copyingClosure.curry(nextToCopy, propertyName)
        copyingClosure = { object, property, value ->
            partialCopy(object.copyWith(createMap(property, value)))
        }
        nextToCopy = nextToCopy.getProperties()[propertyName]
        return this
    }

    void setProperty(String property, Object value) {
        result = copyingClosure.call(nextToCopy, property, value)
        reset()
    }

    private void reset() {
        nextToCopy = result
        copyingClosure = simplyCopy
    }
}
```

It is then just a matter of adding the delegated method in Delivery class:

```
Delivery copyOn(Closure closure) {
    CopyingDelegate.copyOn(this, closure)
}
```

## High level explanation:

First of all it is required to notice that the code of: `delivery.recipient.address.street = newStreet` is interpreted as:

1. Accessing `recipient` property of `delivery` object
2. Accessing `address` of what was the result of the above
3. Assigning property `street` with the value of *newStreet*

Of course the class `CopyingProxy` does not have any of those properties, so `propertyMissing` method will be involved.

So as you can see it is a chain of `propertyMissing` method invocations terminated by running `setProperty`.

### Base case

In order to implement the desired functionality we maintain two fields: `nextToCopy` (which is *delivery* at the beginning) and `copyingClosure` (which is initialised as a simple copy using `copyWith` method provided by `@Immutable(copyWith = true)` transformation).

At this point if we had a simple code like `delivery.copyOn { it.id = '123' }` then it would be evaluated as `delivery.copyWith [id:'123']` according to `simplyCopy` and `setProperty` implementations.

### Recursive step

Let's now see how would it work with one more level of copying: `delivery.copyOn { it.recipient.name = 'newName' }`.

First of all we will set initial values of `nextToCopy` and `copyingClosure` while creating `CopyingProxy` object same way as in the previous example.

Let's now analyse what would happen during first `propertyMissing(String propertyName)` call. So we would capture current `nextToCopy` (delivery object), `copyingClosure` (simple copying based on copyWith) and `propertyName` (*recipient*) in a curried function - `partialCopy`.

Then this copying will be incorporated in  a closure

```
{ object, property, value -> partialCopy(object.copyWith(createMap(property, value))) }
```

which becomes our new `copyingClosure`. In the next step this `copyingClojure` is invoked in the way described in **Base Case** part.

### Conclusion

We have then executed: `delivery.recipient.copyWith [name:'newName']`. And then the `partialCopy` applied to the result of that giving us `delivery.copyWith[recipient:delivery.recipient.copyWith(name:'newName')]`

So it's basically a tree of `copyWith` method invocations.

On top of that you can see some fiddling with `result` field and `reset` function. It was required to support more than one assignments in one closure:

```
delivery.copyOn { 
    it.recipient.address.street = newStreet
    it.id = 'newId' 
}
```